# Deploy Spring project web service for Android

Tags: android, spring, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

I am working on a project built using Spring, Struts 2 and Hibernate and I need to build a web service for an Android Application . I've started to read about web services I understood the difference between SOAP and REST . But I still have problems in how should I proceed to deploy my web Service .

there a lot of technical concepts that I still don't understand .

Would you please help me with your instructions ?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP means creating a SOAP XML message and sending it to the service via HTTP.

REST is more of a style than a standard.  You use the HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE) and map URLs to manipulate data on the server side.

In either case you'd use a Java EE app server or Tomcat or Jetty to deploy a WAR file containing your service.  Then your Android client will create HTTP requests and send them along.

You'll want that service to listen on port 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS.  No worries about firewalls that way.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how can I deploy my web service . I've read about JAX-WS and JAX2 . What's the difference betweeen the two and which one is better and easier ?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like I'm being short, but you have to deploy on a server.  That might be AWS or Rackspace or OpenShift or some other cloud service where you can deploy your service and make it available on the public internet.  Don't worry about "better" or "easier"; figure out how to make one work.  Pick one and run with it.  Change if it becomes impossible.